# Sensitivity derived from Scikit_Learn Confusion Matrix and Scikit_Learn Recall_Score doesn't match

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

```
true = [1,0,0,1]
predict = [1,1,1,1]

cf = sk.metrics.confusion_matrix(true,predict)
print cf
```

array

([[0, 2],

[0, 2]])

```
tp = cf[0][0]
fn = cf[0][1]
fp = cf[1][0]
tn = cf[1][1]
sensitivity= tp/(tp+fn)
print(sensitivity)
```

0.0

```
print(sk.metrics.recall_score(true, predict))
```

1.0

As per Scikit documentation "[Recall_Score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html#sklearn.metrics.recall_score)" definition has to match.
Can somebody explain bit more about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confusion matrix labels must be updated in following way:

```
tn = cf[0][0]
fp = cf[0][1]
fn = cf[1][0]
tp = cf[1][1]
sensitivity= tp/(tp+fn)
print(sensitivity)

1.0
```